# New values not showing at div (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have div in main view where I show data after AJAX request

here is code

```
<div class="count" style="height: 80%; width: 100%; overflow-y: auto;" id="style-1">


            </div>
```

I adding new values via modal window here is script for adding

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#save_quest').click(function () {
       savequestion();
      });
});

// Сохранение вопроса в модальном окне
function savequestion() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        dataType: 'Json',
        data: {
            Question_new: $('#question').val(),
            Answer: $('#answer').val(),
            Preparing: $('#prepare').val(),
            Retries: $('#retries').val(),
        },
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateNewQuestion", "Questions")',
        success: function (da) {
            if (da.Result === "Success") {
                $('#myModal').hide();
                } else {
                alert('Error' + da.Message);
            }
        },
        error: function (da) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

And I update `count` div by save button too.

Here is script

```
<script>
$('#save_quest').click(function () {
    emails_update();
});
function emails_update() {
    $(".count").empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("QuestionsList", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var email = result;
            // console.log(result[0].Name);
            for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++) {
                var arrow  = '@Url.Content("~/Images/plus_plus.png")';
                var edit = '@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")';
                var questionHtml = '<div class = "title" style="margin-top:15px;margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:10px;">'
                    +
                    '<img class="click" src="'
                    + arrow
                    + '">' +
                    '<span class="test">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="testclass" readonly value="' +
                    result[i].Quest + '">' +'<a style="margin-left:25px;">'+'<img src=">'+ edit+'">' +
                    '</div>';
                $(".count").append(questionHtml);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

All is adding succesfully, but new values not showing in div.

where is my problem?

Comment: Did you debug it? What is the value of questionHtml in your success callback?

Comment: Yes. I see olв values , and new value is in table. If I add one more, I will see old ones + previous, but not new@mariocatch

Answer (score 0):

`questionHtml` is `string` and it won't work with `append` the way your are using it.

try this instead:

```
$(questionHtml).appendTo(".count");
```

and you don't even need the var in this case

```
$('<div class = "title" style="margin-top:15px;margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:10px;">'  +
  '<img class="click" src="' + arrow + '">' +
  '<span class="test">' +
  '<input type="text" class="testclass" readonly value="' +
  result[i].Quest + '">' +'<a style="margin-left:25px;">'+'<img src=">'+ edit+'">' +
  '</div>').appendTo('.count');
```

Comment: It seems works. I have another trouble. When I add new value and click savebutton I don't see it. I will see it if add second value.

Answer (score 0):

I already solve problem I need to do update if sucess  returns.

Like this

```
 if (da.Result === "Success") {
                $('#myModal').hide();
                emails_update();
```